# How do I make a struct point in python?

Tags: python, c++, tetris

I'm making a Tetris clone in Pygame based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zH_omFPqMO4 and I need to know how to turn

```
struct Point
{int x,y;} a[4],b[4];
```

into Python from C++.

Comment: Just don't try to convert C++ to Python line by line, that usually doesn't work. Try to understand what the C++ code is doing a rewrite in python. Different languages work in different ways . Even if the code looks similar, python and C++ handle memory and lifetime of objects differently. So usually : learn both languages, try to understand the algorithms and then you can rewrite in the target language.

Answer (score 0):

So the C++ code, `struct point {int x, y} a[4], b[4]` creates a new `structure` which is a data type with two ints `x` and `y`. The `a[4]` and `b[4]` are two created arrays of type `point` and each of size `4`.

To replicate a `structure` in python we could use a `class`

Example:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

a = []
b = []

# Creating an instance of the Point object
myPoint = Point(5, 6)

# Adding said point to our array
a.append(myPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm going to echo what was said in the comments: Do not try to do a direct translation. Write your project fresh in Python. Python does things differently. In C++, you deal with memory and justifying what's safe to do with memory. In Python, you deal directly with classes at a high-level. They're at different levels of abstraction, and trying to translate directly is going to result in very awkward and stilted code.

Regardless, the way to write a `Point` type in Python naively with a class would be

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

But this leaves a lot to be desired. For one, points are not comparable for equality. For another, if you try to print them out, you'll get some sort of awkward Python pointer-like syntax. Instead, for basic structure-like data, you want [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).

```
@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float
```

Now you get equality and stringification for free, as well as a nice constructor and a `replace` function for creating similar instances. If you're planning to make your `Point` objects immutable (which is a great idea and I highly recommend), then you can throw a `frozen=True` as argument to the `dataclass` decorator and get hashing for free as well. This means that you can use points as keys to dictionaries.

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float
```

On top of this, you'll probably want to implement [magic methods](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/) like `__add__` so you can use operators like `+` on your `Point` type (reader beware: that article I linked has some outdated bits from Python 2. Definitely read Appendix 2 for the differences, but it's still one of the best summaries of magic methods out there, in spite of its age)

Answer (score 0):

Here we use list comprehension to create list of size 4 with each element initialized to Point(0,0)

```
class Point: 
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x 
        self.f = y    

#create lists named a of size 4 
a = [Point(p-p,p-p) for p in range(4) ]  #equivalent to a = [Point(0,0), Point(0,0), Point(0,0), Point(0,0)

#create list named b of size 4
b = [Point(p-p,p-p) for p in range(4) ]
```

Answer (score -1):

so a class is just struct in C++?

```
struct Point{int x,y;}a[4]b[4]
```

is

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

a = []
b = []

# Creating an instance of the Point object
myPoint = Point(5, 6)

# Adding said point to our array
a.append(myPoint)
b.append(myPoint)
```

?